# Why does TS do not get React state assertion from Interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So, I have this component:

```
type TypeofArray<
    ArrayTypeInstance
> = ArrayTypeInstance extends (infer ElementType)[] ? ElementType : never;

type Property = {
    dataId: number;
    address: string;
    price?: number;
    transactionType: string;
    bedrooms?: number;
    coverImageUrl?: string;
    modifiedWhen: string;
    currentStage?: string;
};

type PropertiesState = {
    searchType: TypeofArray<typeof SEARCH_TYPES>;
    properties: Property[];
    [key: number]: boolean;
};

export class Properties extends Component<{}, PropertiesState> {
    readonly state = {
        searchType: 'buy',
        properties: []
    };
...
```

And here I am trying access this piece of state `[key: number]: boolean;`:

```
 <PropertyCard
                    isFavorite={this.state[property.dataId]}
                />
```

But I get this error:

**Error:(98, 33) TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ searchType: string; properties: never[]; }' has no index signature.**

If I explicitly annotate state like this:

```
readonly state: PropertiesState = {
    searchType: 'buy',
    properties: []
};
```

error disappears.

Why? What is better way to fix this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring `state = { searchType: 'buy', properties: [] }` narrows the type of `state` to `{ searchType: 'buy', properties: never[] }` (`never[]` essentially being an empty array). Depending of your compiler settings, `properties` may be narrowed to `any[]` instead.

This happens because TypeScript infers types from property declarations. Those inferred types override any shadowed types from extended classes such as `React.Component`.

To resolve, there's a few options:

1. Re-widen the type as you did by annotating `state` with `PropertiesState`
2. Re-widen by casting `state = { /* ... */ } as PropertiesState`.
3. Assign `this.state` in the constructor to avoid narrowing:

```
export class Properties extends Component<{}, PropertiesState> {
    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
        state = {
            searchType: 'buy',
            properties: []
        };
    }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it was helpful!